# Accessing Openstack instances

Tags: openstack

As far as I know, Openstack is a platform for virtualization and helps in efficiently creating and managing virtual machines. After creating two virtual machines on how can I use them or how can I deploy them? Can I access those instances from other locations in a network using their IP addresses?

Answer (score 1):

Openstack allows to access instances from external network's also (external to openstack).
But it completely depends on the on your flat network ( floating Ip address network ) . if those are public IP's then you can access your instances from anywhere.